# 'Mysql2' is defined in database adapter, but its asking to add gem 'sqlite3'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite3-ruby, rails-3-upgrade

I have recently upgraded rails to `4.2.X latest` from `3.2.19`. Also upgraded ruby to `2.2.2` from `1.9.2`. 
When trying to run spec using `$ rspec .` command, I got this following error:

> Could not load native IDN implementation.
>   /Users.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:178:in
>   rescue in spec': Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the
>   gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its
>   version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)

Used `Mysql2` adapter for all environments. But it is asking to add `sqlite3` in Gemfile.

After debugging inside `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters` module, found this config hash `{:adapter=>"sqlite3", :database=>":memory:"}`. Don't know where it is getting `sqlite3` adapter.

Comment: Can you post your config/database.yml file?

Comment: development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: abc_development
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: abc_test
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: abc_development
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

Comment: Everything seems fine. Have you tried to clean your gems in case there's some old thing not being used anymore? You can run:

$ bundle clean --force